# How to fix blurry MySQL Workbench 6.3 on Windows 10.1709?

Tags: windows-10, mysql, windows-10-v1709

I'm running MySQL Workbench 6.3 on Windows 10.1709. The application looks blurry, as if the pixels had been run through a Photoshop Soft-Focus Filter.

I cannot upgrade to MySQL Workbench 8.0 because I run into an unresolvable version of [this other unrelated issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739198/mysql-workbench-not-displaying-query-results/46938670).

I cannot upgrade to Windows 10.1803 to take advantage of the **Let Windows try to fix apps so they’re not blurry** feature [documented here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4091364/windows-10-fix-blurry-apps)

So, assuming I'm stuck with these versions of software for now, is there any way to work-around this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you need a dedecated monitor which runs at a native resolution, that will result in the text not being blurry, since your unable to use the native solution built into 1803

Comment: I assume you have tried [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15078/windows-make-older-programs-compatible) solution?